# Differentiate causes of Activity being destroyed

Tags: android

I want to differentiate two causes of Activity being destroyed.
1. The Activity is killed by Android OS but the process is not killed.
2. User rotates the phone so the Activity is destroyed.

Is there any good way to differentiate these two causes?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "The Activity is killed by Android OS but the process is not killed".

Comment: When the system memory is low, it may kill the activity or the process. Right?
Android has a 'Don't  keep activities' developer option to simulate this case.

Comment: Android terminates processes due to low memory conditions. [It does not destroy activities due to low memory conditions](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html).

Comment: So OS will never automatically destroy a backgrounded Activity? What is 'Don't keep activities' developer option for?

Comment: As the option states, it "destroys every activity as soon as the user leaves it". This is designed to force you to think about configuration changes.

Comment: As far as conditions goes, you need to be more specific: If your activity is terminated, the `onDestroy()` function is guaranteed to be called. If your activity is being terminated due to a rotation (and will be created again), then `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` is guaranteed to be called, IF you add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your manifest